# Boot Problems After 16.04.1 Upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, upstart

The upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS failed and exited on mythtvexport due to a previously failed install that I had forgotten about.  This module has since been removed.

The upgrade continued in background mode but not realising this, I rebooted on a couple of occasions. The upgrade seemed to complete ok but now, on rebooting, hangs on the black screen displaying "UBUNTU" with 5 red dots underneath.

Rebooting and going into the grub menu, there is now an additional "upstart" option for each version of the kernel.  The system can only be booted by selecting one of these options (usually the latest version but I did try several other versions of the non "upstart" option - non worked). There have been at least 2 subsequent kernel upgrades but these have not affected the boot process.

I understand that "upstart" has been replaced by "systemd" at 16.04. Can you advise on the best way forward please. Also, mythtv backend no longer starts automatically but the front end does. Can you help on this as well please.

Many thanks

Paul

Comment: Best to just reinstall using a Ubuntu 16.04.1 Live DVD. Regarding mythtv backend, in `terminal` type `sudo systemctl status mysql` and confirm that mysql is running.

Comment: Never upgrade. New installation is always faster and more stable. Even now, after upgrade, I would recommend a fresh installation instead of hunting errors.

Comment: Thanks  @heynnema and oxidworks.  Re mythtv back end, all I need to do is start the task (sudo service mythtv-backend start) and the front end connects to it. From that point on it works fine until the next reboot. I think what happened is that the startup job got moved from the upstart location to the systemd location. Systemd is installed but obviously not implemented properly, possibly due to a reboot that I did, so who knows what else didn't get done. Not sure about reinstalling and how that would work. Don't want to lose mythtv recordings or the mirror raid configuration.

Comment: Technically, you should `sudo systemctl start mythtv-backend.service`. You should check `sudo systemctl status mythtv-backend.service` and confirm that the service is `enabled` and `running`. Since the reboots during the upgrade, you don't know what you've got. In the Ubuntu installer, I'd choose the `reinstall` option and make sure that the `format` partition is unchecked, and it'll keep your /home folder.

Comment: What about mytytv and all the settings and recordings

Comment: Oh and systemctl status returned Failed to get properties: No such interface

Comment: If `sudo systemctl status mythtv-backend.service` returned that error, then that explains why your backend isn't starting. Reinstall MythTV. MythTV recordings are in /var/lib/mythtv/recordings, and they'll probably be gone, unless you try and back them up.

Comment: ps: but as I said, you really need to just reinstall 16.04.1, 'cause systemd didn't get installed right, and gosh knows what else. Save yourself some future grief.